# Solving for x in a complex trigonometric equation

Tags: python, sympy, cmath

I need to write a script that solves for a variable inside a complex numbers-trigonometric equation, how do i solve it?

So far I tried using the Eq function from sympy to input the equation from which I need to isolate x, and then using the solve/solveset functions, however this is not working. I have already isolated by hand through algebra,  but i wanted to know if it's possible in anyway to calculate its value without having to input the isolated equation for the variable.

```py
import cmath
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
Zl = complex(20, -10)
Z0 = 75

pl = abs((Zl - Z0)/(Zl + Z0))
SWR = (1 + pl)/(1 - pl)

eq = Eq(SWR, (Zl + 1j*(Z0*SWR*cmath.tan(2*cmath.pi*x)))/(Z0 + 1j*(Zl*SWR*cmath.tan(2*cmath.pi*x))))
m = solve(eq)
print(m)
```

I expect the output to be `(-0.22734187163019368+7.138384643986063e-18j)`, which is what i got by solving it by hand. (`m = cmath.atan(1j*(Z0*SWR-Zl)/(Zl*SWR - Z0))/(2*cmath.pi)`)

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/juank/PycharmProjects/TXScripts/solveM_givenSWR.py", line 16, in <module>
    eq = Eq(SWR, (Zl + 1j*(Z0*SWR*cmath.tan(2*cmath.pi*x)))/(Z0 + 1j*(Zl*SWR*cmath.tan(2*cmath.pi*x))))
  File "C:\Users\juank\PycharmProjects\TXScripts\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 285, in __complex__
    return complex(float(re), float(im))
  File "C:\Users\juank\PycharmProjects\TXScripts\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 280, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Comment: You have a type error. Something in there is not converting to a float (one reason I like typed languages is this issue should be caught by the compiler). Can you take that large equation and break it up into many smaller ones? Find which portion is giving issues. Do each set of parenthesis on it's own line and store it in a variable.

Comment: ok, i realized that the main problem lays in the fact that ```math.tan()``` cannot take the x as it is symbolic and not a complex nor a float like it expects. How can I work around this?

Comment: If any of the answers are correct, please accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using `cmath` with `sympy`. Replace all `cmath` functions with their `sympy` equivalent. `sympy` has its own trigonometric functions. The `cmath` versions are expecting a float.

I prefer to explicitly import so I know which library I'm using such as:

`from sympy import tan as sy_tan, symbols, complex` (the `as` is optional)

Namespace issues with commonly named functions will always create issues.